# How to make my app NOT support tablets

Tags: android, google-play, tablet

When I am trying to publish my app on Google play, it is said that my app support tablets so I need to upload the screen shots of the tablets .

BUT I want to make my app for smartphones only. how ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a [supports-screen](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html) element in the manifest.

For example:

```
<supports-screens
              android:smallScreens="true"
              android:normalScreens="true"
              android:largeScreens="false"
              android:xlargeScreens="false"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `supports-screens` and `largestWidthLimitDp`

see the docs here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html

And overall explanation here http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html